# Linking images in jquery smootscroll

Tags: jquery, image, smooth-scrolling

I used a jquery plugin to create an endless scroll: [http://go.nbm.org/site/PageNavigator/museum shop/general shop site pages/Shop_Slider_Test.html](http://go.nbm.org/site/PageNavigator/museum%20shop/general%20shop%20site%20pages/Shop_Slider_Test.html)

I want to link each image to a different page though. I tried to do so using:

```
    <img src="../images/content/pagebuilder/a.toy_banner.jpg" border="0" alt="The Toy Shop Banner" width="670" height="290" /></p>
<div id="makeMeScrollable" style="width: 670px; height: 160px;">
<div class="scrollingHotSpotLeft" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
<div class="scrollingHotSpotRight" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
<div class="scrollWrapper">
<div class="scrollableArea" style="width: 963px;">
<a target="_self" href"Ecommerce/1940604903?FOLDER=1340&amp;store_id=1161">
     <img src="../images/content/pagebuilder/kidsbooks_button.jpg" alt="Kids Books"  />
</a>
<a target="_self" href"Ecommerce/1940604903?FOLDER=1086&amp;store_id=1161">
     <img src="../images/content/pagebuilder/games_button.jpg" alt="Games"  />
</a>
<a target="_self" href"Ecommerce/1940604903?FOLDER=1089&amp;store_id=1161">
     <img src="../images/content/pagebuilder/kidsdecor_button_1.jpg" alt="Kids Decor"  />
</a>
<a target="_self" href"Ecommerce/1940604903?FOLDER=1934&amp;store_id=1161">
    <img src="../images/content/pagebuilder/models_button.jpg" alt="Models"  />
</a>
<a target="_self" href"Ecommerce/1940604903?FOLDER=1930&amp;store_id=1161">
    <img src="../images/content/pagebuilder/science_button.jpg" alt="Science"  />
</a>
<a target="_self" href"Ecommerce/1940604903?FOLDER=1084&amp;store_id=1161">
    <img src="../images/content/pagebuilder/toys_button.jpg" alt="Toys"  />
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But then the images no longer scroll. Instead, only one image sits at the left of the div and they scroll through individually in that space, rather than in a line.

Any advice??
I'm still a novice at most of this, so I may be missing something really obvious. But I'd really appreciate any help.